# Problem with installation of the security module of Banco do Brasil // Problema com instalação do módulo de segurança do Banco do Brasil

Tags: 16.04, firefox

I'm trying to access the internet banking by Firefox on my Ubuntu 16.04, but even with the security module installed, it does not work.

Internet Banking Message:

[image: image here]

I ran a warsaw status and it looks like everything is normal:

[image: image here]

I already tested it on Google Chrome and it looks like Firefox.

I followed the BB tutorial, installed by .run and .deb, but without success (https://seg.bb.com.br/duvidas.html).

How can I debug/fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Firefox doesn't support the Java plugin anymore](https://www.cso.com.au/article/615493/firefox-52-drops-java-plugin-support-expands-http-secure-warnings/), which [the Warsaw whatever requires](http://andreimikhailov.com/banco-do-brasil-online/Security_module.html). There is one exception: the soon-to-be-unsupported-with-security-fixes [Firefox 52 ESR 32-bit version supports Java](https://java.com/en/download/help/firefox_java.xml).

With that said, I'd strongly recommend switching banks. Continuing to require Java when it's very well-known that nearly all modern browsers no longer support it *partly because of its repeated security holes* is a sign of complete incompetence on the part of the bank's IT department. In fact, requiring administrative access to a user's system to use a website is almost always the sign of someone who doesn't care about computer security and who shouldn't be trusted with anything requiring security.